# Zeek (Bro) goes crashed after interface gets restarted

Tags: zeek

I have some issues with the zeek software. After the network interface eth0 gets restarted the zeekctl goes crashed. Is there any way of restart the zeekctl process automatically after a network interface gets restarted? Thanks in advance.

```
tail -f /opt/zeek/logs/current/reporter.log

#separator \x09
#set_separator ,
#empty_field (empty)
#unset_field -
#path reporter
#open 2021-10-16-23-26-34
#fields ts level message location
#types time enum string string
1634441194.496057 Reporter::ERROR failed to read a packet from eth0: The interface went down (empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

`zeekctl` is management software for Zeek, so when Zeek crashes, you can normally use `zeekctl` to diagnose that fact and restart nodes as needed.

Failure to read from a device that was previously running shouldn't cause Zeek to exit, so make sure that this is what actually happened. The reporter.log message you're showing only indicates that Zeek noticed that the interface went away.

You can use `zeekctl start <node>` or `zeekctl restart <node>` to start/restart a particular node in your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I understand you perfectly, but the problem lies in how to make zeekctl trigger automatically the restart of the node that attends to the down interface. I have tried using the zeekctl cron but it does not restart the node attending the restarted interface.

Comment: Despite the fact that the node that attends the restarted interface remains in a running state, zeek stops generating logs in /opt/zeek/logs/current/'s folder.

Comment: I'm not sure we'll get to the bottom of this here — you may want to swing by the Zeek Slack for more direct communication. I'm curious what packet capture technology you're using. Over here I don't see Zeek exiting when an interface goes down, and monitoring continues as before when it comes back up.